# how to make phone call from html website

Tags: html, mobile, cross-browser, mobile-safari

I am using a html anchor tag with tel attribute.but it not working on all mobile browsers.I serached on google for its solution but not found any solution.Any help will be appreciated
I am using below code for phone call.

```
<a href="tel:18475555555">1-847-555-5555</a>
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169976/whats-a-reliable-method-for-setting-up-telephone-links-for-mobile-browsers

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working on all mobile browsers"? Which browsers on what OSs?

Comment: What phones are you talking about? A lot of older phones don't support newer things like this